# Unable to load DLL 'ml32i4.dll' when calling .NETLink for .NET Framework 4.6.1 application

Tags: .netlink

I have added Wolfram.NETLink to a C# .NET Framework 4.6.1 application via NuGet. NuGet installs this to the `C:\Users\[user]\.nuget\packages\wolfram.netlink\1.7.1` folder.

I have a C# application and am trying to execute the following code:

```
   try 
   {
       string[] mlArgs = { "-linkmode", "launch", "-linkname", "C:/Program Files/Wolfram Research/Wolfram Engine/13.1/wolfram.exe" };
       kernelLink = MathLinkFactory.CreateKernelLink(mlArgs);
       kernelLink.WaitAndDiscardAnswer();
   }
   catch(MathLinkException mlEx)
   {
       engineStatus = mlEx.Message;
   }
```

The call to `kernelLink = MathLinkFactory.CreaterKernelLink(mlArgs);` throws an exception:

```
"Unable to load DLL 'ml32i4.dll': The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)"}   System.Exception {System.DllNotFoundException}
```

**What I have tried so far:**

1. Copied `Wolfram.NETLink.DLL` and `ml32i4.dll` to the same folder as the application executable. This has no effect.
2. Set a reference path to the same folder. This has no effect.

**Questions**

1. Are there additional dependencies required by `Wolfram.NETLink.DLL` and `ml32i4.dll`?

**No**

2. NuGet added a reference to the project for the `Wolfram.NETLink` assembly. Do I need to manually add a reference to the project for `ml32i4.dll`?

**No**

**Solution**

1. Add the output directory folder specification to the machine `%PATH%` environmental variable.

Comment: The 32 in ml32i4.dll means 32-bit.  Are you targeting your app for 64 bit?  [MS docs page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-options/output#platformtarget)

Comment: 32-bit in this case.